# gridview and radio button list on browser back button

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my aspx page there is a RadioButtonList and it contains list items named “additions” and “termination”. Also there two gridview “GV_addition” and “GV_termination”. On selecting the radio button “addition”, then the gridview “GV_addition” will be shown. When item “termination” is selected, then the gridview “GV_termination” will be shown.

On radio button changed event, it is working correctly. But my problem is , when I click browser back button, the radio button selection and corresponding grid view not showing correctly. I got issue, “Gv_termination” is showing when radio button “addition” is selected. This issue is showing only when I click browser back button.

Please find my below code

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="addition" Value="addition"> </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="termination" Value="termination"></asp:ListItem>
```

```
   protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            GV_addition.Visible = true;
            GV_termination.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GV_termination.Visible = true;
            GV_addition.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I could not understand why the why the radio button selection and corresponding gridview visiblity is not working on the browsers back button event. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below steps. For me the same scenario worked.

I could see the values are updating correctly, but the updated radio checked states are not updating in to the UI. So I have set it using javacript on the Onload event of a body.

Add the Onload event on the body.

```
<body onload="setRadioButonStatus()">
```

and add the following Javascript.

```
       function setRadioButonStatus() {
            var rbtn1 = document.getElementById('RadioButton1');
            var rbtn2 = document.getElementById('RadioButton2');

            if (rbtn1.hasAttribute("checked"))
                rbtn1.checked = true;
            if (rbtn2.hasAttribute("checked"))
                rbtn2.checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: ASP server controls don't retain the same client ID as their server ID, so I'm not sure this will work.  When the page is loaded, the DOM ID of RadioButton1 will not be "RadioButton1".

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you aren't creating a "default" scenario.  You can do this, and tie the logic together more closely by doing something like this on every Page_Load and leaving it out of your event.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GV_addition.Visible = RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0;
        GV_termination.Visible = RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1;
    }



protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```